# How to get uri of captured image from file provider in onActivityResult?

Tags: android, image, uri, onactivityresult, android-fileprovider

I have successfully saved my captured image in my device gallery using the file provider function. However I do not know how to do my OnActivityResult to get the image captured in my app using uri.

This is my current OnActivityResult. (Please note that case 'REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE_IN_ALBUM' function works well, it managed to retrieve the image selected from gallery and set it in the image view in 'DetectionActivity' using this OnActivityResult code.)

```
 // Deal with the result of selection of the photos and faces.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
            case REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE_IN_ALBUM:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri imageUri;
                    if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                        imageUri = mUriPhotoTaken;
                    } else {
                        imageUri = data.getData();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setData(imageUri);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

This is how I use file provider for takePhoto function.

```
// When the button of "Take a Photo with Camera" is pressed.
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void takePhoto(View v) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            invokeCamera();
        } else {
            // let's request permission
            String[] permissionRequest = {CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissionRequest, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {

            // we have heard back from our request for camera and write external storage
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                invokeCamera();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.cannotopencamera, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public void invokeCamera () {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        //get a file reference
        mUriPhotoTaken = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile());

        //tell the camera where to save the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUriPhotoTaken);

        //tell the camera to request WRITE permission
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

    }

    private File createImageFile() {
        //the public picture directory
        File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        //timestamp makes unique name
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String timestamp = sdf.format(new Date());

        //put together the directory and the timestamp to make a unique image location.
        File imageFile = new File(picturesDirectory, "picture" + timestamp + ".jpg");
 return imageFile;
    }

    // When the button of "Select a Photo in Album" is pressed.
    public void selectImageInAlbum(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE_IN_ALBUM);
        }
    }

}
```

My DetectionActivity is the activity that will get the captured image and set it in the imageview

```
// Called when image selection is done.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // If image is selected successfully, set the image URI and bitmap.
                    mImageUri = data.getData();
                    mBitmap = ImageHelper.loadSizeLimitedBitmapFromUri(
                            mImageUri, getContentResolver());
                    if (mBitmap != null) {
                        // Show the image on screen.
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

                        // Add detection log.
                        addLog("Image: " + mImageUri + " resized to " + mBitmap.getWidth()
                                + "x" + mBitmap.getHeight());
                    }

                    // Clear the detection result.
                    FaceListAdapter faceListAdapter = new FaceListAdapter(null);
                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_detected_faces);
                    listView.setAdapter(faceListAdapter);

                    // Clear the information panel.
                    setInfo("");

                    // Enable button "detect" as the image is selected and not detected.
                    setDetectButtonEnabledStatus(true);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "However I do not know how to do my OnActivityResult to get the image captured in my app using uri." -- it looks like your `Uri` is saved as `mUriPhotoTaken`.

Comment: Yes thats what I did but my captured image doesnt set to imageview right after. If i'm using file provider can I still use the code if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                        imageUri = mUriPhotoTaken;
                    } else {
                        imageUri = data.getData();
                    } in my OnActivityResult? @CommonsWare

Comment: You need to make sure that you hold onto details of `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the saved instance state `Bundle`. Your app's process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground. [This sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider) is getting a bit old but demonstrates the basic technique.